# Jquery .live() still doesn't run functions correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, live

Though I have seen other posts similar, I haven't been able to find out the exact cause/solution to my problem, so I hope i'm not just reposting what others have asked:

I recently discovered that in jquery the .live() allows my functions to be attached to items which are dynamically added into the page. So I have a list of items, i click delete which uses the get function, using the href as a get variable, which then deletes that item from my database and refreshes the list.

So with the live function, I managed to then have this same function added to the refreshed list. The problem however is that the get variable specifiying which item to delete seems stuck on the last number.

So if I delete item 13, then the list refreshed, and I try to delete say item 15, it seems (from firebug) that the get variable is again attempting to delete item 13 and not 15

apologies for the messy code to follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delav').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                var pager = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal:true,
          buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() {
                  $('#ava_list').html("Loading..");

            var pai =$('#epa_id').val();
                $.get("/_includes/functions.php", { table: "availability", pa: pai,delattr: pager} ,function(data) {$('#ava_list').html(data);});
            $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        });

        $("#dialog2").dialog("open");

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using $.live() the JQuery refrence recommends the use of delegates

```
    $('.highlevelclasshere').delegate('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var pager = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 600,
           modal:true,
        buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
              $('#ava_list').html("Loading..");

        var pai =$('#epa_id').val();
            $.get("/_includes/functions.php", { table: "availability", pa: pai,delattr:         pager} ,function(data) {$('#ava_list').html(data);});
        $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#dialog2").dialog("open");

});
```

Comment: Hi Thankyou for your quick response. I tried using delegate and it had an error saying that it is not a function

Comment: Is there anyway you could post the code that gave you that error? I belive I received that before when I declared the function incorrectly.

Comment: I looked it up an I had a lower version of jquery. But now the new jquery give me this error

Error: (a || "").split is not a function
Source File: site/ui/jquery1.6.min.js
Line: 17

Comment: `(a || "").split`? Unless you are missing something in your comment shouldnt it be `(a | "").split('stringToSplitBy');` as `.split` most defiantly isn't a function?

Comment: This came simply from adding in the new jquery version. Although I think it is something to do with the delegate function

Comment: I seem to have used the delegate wrong. Now ive corrected it, but hte function has no longer triggered on click

Comment: Ok that seems like a problem with what you made as the delegate's parent, it should be a non dynamic parent, preably a container of sometime

Comment: $('#tabs').delegate('.delaval', 'click', function(e) {is what i changed to and removed the document ready wrapper... but this doesnt add a function at all, simple follow the link

Comment: WOW - theres a few hours ill never get back... thank you both guys. I did a combination of setting the cache to false, and then I also declared pager outside of the click event in the hope that would allow it to be assigned a new value per click. One or both did the trick

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that you have multiple input elements with the ID 'epa_id'. If that is the case, you will need to remove duplicate IDs and employ DOM traversal to grab the correct element relative to the clicked `.delav` instead.

For a specific solution, we will need to see your markup.

Comment: the epa_id is only used once. The second number which is dynamic, I store in the href. But when I dynamically load new links, the new hrefs dont get used when using live, and delegate doesnt seem to work at all

Comment: Try setting `cache` to `false` in the `$.get` options.

Comment: WOW - theres a few hours ill never get back... thank you both guys. I did a combination of setting the cache to false, and then I also declared pager outside of the click event in the hope that would allow it to be assigned a new value per click. One or both did the trick